# How to bind object properties to this keyword on javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, pixi.js

How can i use **this** keyword  to access , change and bind PIXI.Sprite's (or another objects ) properties to  function scope . Using different name for other than **this** seems absurd but i can't figure it out .

What is correct way to solve this kind of oop problems on **javascript** .

```
function createEmoji(x , y ) {
    let t = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage(`assets/image (${1+~~(Math.random()*80)}).png`);
    let i = new PIXI.Sprite(t);

    i.anchor.set(.5);
    i.angle = Math.random() * 360;
    i.mag = Math.random() * 3;
    i.x = x;
    i.vx = Math.cos(i.angle) * i.mag;
    i.rotation = i.angle;
    i.tint = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
    i.y = y;
    i.vy = Math.sin(i.angle) * i.mag;
    i.ax = 0;
    i.ay = 0;
    i.speed = Math.random() / 100;

    container.addChild(i);
    return i;
}
```

Adding **i.bind(this)** gives

```
Uncaught TypeError: i.bind is not a function
at new createEmoji
```

**UPDATE**

Okey i understand this with javascript's so called class keyword.

```
class createEmoji extends PIXI.Sprite {
    constructor(x, y) {
        super();
        this.texture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage("assets/emoji.png");
        this.x = app.rw;//random position method for x and y
        this.y = app.rh;
        this.t = Vec(x, y, test, window);//another method returns ObservablePoint
        this.scale.set(.5 + Math.random() * .5);
        this.anchor.set(.5);

    }
}
```

this fixed the problem which i was looking  for.

Comment: Let me see if I understood this right: you want to bind `this` to an object *from inside the function* in which you are using / want to use `this` itself? that is, you want `this` to refer to `i` inside that function call?

Comment: Yes . I want to use this.x or this.something instead of using i or whatever the name of  that object

Comment: Is there a reason for that or is that just something you want just because? Maybe you're tryig to solve a problem the wrong way?

Comment: I don't know , it just seems wrong not to use  **this** keyword because function return something else other than itself .Maybe i should try prototypes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change what `this` refers to inside the body of a function.

There are four ways of determining what `this` refers to:

- You can call a funcion as a property of an object (`obj.func()`), so that the object is bound to `this` inside the function.
- You can use `new` to instantiate an object from a "class".  This will bind `this` inside the function to an object that has your function `prototype` property as its prototype, that will also be the (default) return value of the `new` expression.  (Essentially, the function receives the object being constructed as `this`, making it a "constructor function").
- You can use the `.bind(obj)` method of a function to generate another function that will *always* have the object bound as `this` when called.
- You can use the `.call(…)` or `.apply(…)` methods and pass whatever object you want as `this` inside the function as the first argument.

As you see, all of those are ways of determining what `this` refers to *from the call site* (or even before, in the case of `bind`), so you just *can't* change what `this` points to from within a function call itself.

---

However, you seem to be struggling a bit with the OOP way of doing things in JavaScript, so let me address your concerns.

You seem to be using your `createEmoji` function as a constructor, but you are returning an instance on `PIXI.Sprite`.  This seems to be the main source of confusion: why would you return something that's not `this` here? It feels wrong.

Indeed, that is not really what you want.  Instead, treat `createEmoji` as a free function.  If you come from a Java background, think `static` methods.  You call it just as `var emoji = createEmoji(...);` and document it as returning a `PIXI.Sprite`.  It's, essentially, a static factory method.  There is no `this` involved in this call now, so luckily you have a clearer picture now.

another solution would be to transform `createEmoji` to a fully fledged `Emoji` class, making the sprite a member of the class (i.e., refering to it as `this.sprite` instead of `i`).  The constructor in this case would have your new emoji instance as `this` and you don't need to return anything.  Unless your emoji needs its own representation and behaviour distinct from a simple sprite, *i would not go this way*, as it's way more complex.

**tl;dr**: Don't use `createEmoji` as a constructor, but as a function that returns a sprite.  Just like that, all your instincts as to what should `this` e are gone, because there's no `this` involved.

Comment: Thank you .I think i have to make couple of more samples to grasp the consept.